# Sending file as chunks from a java client to server

Tags: java, streaming, client-server

I wrote a java client which takes in the buffer_size for the byte array as a command line argument and declares a byte array in which as file will be read and sent to the server in chunks. Client will send the buffer_size to the java server before starting to read the file so that the server can also define a byte array to receive the file chunks. So this mechanism looks something like....

Client Side:

```
while ((count = fileReader.read(bytes)) > 0) {
    toServer.write(bytes, 0, count);
}
```

Server Side:

```
while ((count = fromClient.read(bytes)) > 0) {
   //process the received file content
}
```

This works right for me. But the behavior of the server reading the chunks changes in a random manner. i.e., If the file that is to be read by the client is of 3000 bytes and the buffer_size if 8192 bytes (the server will also have a buffer_size of 8192), the server reads the whole chunk(from the client) with a single read() operation and sometimes the chunk is divided into 2 parts and read (as two 1500 bytes for example, taking up 2 read() operations). I don't understand what exactly happens here. Can we implement this in such a that the server doesn't divide the chunk which is being sent by the client?!

When it is tested by running both client and server in the local machine, server reads the whole content sent by the client using one write() operation with just one read() operation. The behavior changes happen only when the client and server is on different machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1500 is probably the MTU of the link. Data is split into packets of such size as it is transfered. When implementing a server, you must simply be prepared for the data to be diced into arbitrarily-sized packets.

The abstraction implemented by TCP is a stream of bytes, not a series of write() calls. To force a specific packet size, you would have to use UDP (and deal with packet loss, as UDP does not guarantee delivery).

To fix this, simply read in a loop until the whole buffer has been read, or the length of the file has been reached. The client can simply send the length of the file at the beginning of the protocol. There is no need for the client and server to use the same buffer size.

Comment: By the way, the reason it works differently on the same host, is that for localhost the MTU is much larger. But it is not unlimited, either. My guess is under Linux if you try to write more than 64KiB it will be split up even over localhost interface.

Comment: yeah got it, and corrected my code too. But the chunks which are being read by the sever doesn't always stay below 1500 bytes while being transferred over the ethernet.